# Restricting linux user to a folder

Tags: linux, security, shell, unix

I need to create a seperate folder for an user where he is allowed to execute only one binary. He can call python/perl and run a program also.
But the user should not be able to delete any folder in his directory and  should not be able to view any other directory. How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

If they are accessing only over ssh, then a `ChrootDirectory` is the way to go.
Simply put, you create a fake `/` system in another directory, with all the programs the user is allowed to run & the libraries they need.

See the `ChrootDirectory` section of the `sshd_config` man page, or somewhere like [Here](http://allanfeid.com/content/creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access) for a fuller guide if needed.

Comment: You may need to bind-mount `/proc/` & `/dev` and some other system directories inside that *chroot*

Answer (score 0):

CHMOD does the job

```
  chmod 755 directory/filename

7 user (**owner**) has full access.
5 allows **group** user "read" and "execute" permissions, but
  not "write" permissions. 
5 allows **others** "read" and "execute" permissions, 
  but not "write" permissions.
```

For your reference :

The 5 allows "read" and "execute" permissions, but not "write" permissions. A 6 would allow read and write permissions, but not "execute". A 4 would be "read" only. A 2 would be "write" only, and a 1 would be "execute" only.

Further Reference : [**link**](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/Example-Uses-Of-The-Command-Chmod.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider configuring and using a **restricted shell** like e.g. a [restricted bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html).

However, notice that if you enable the user to run a scripting language like `Python` he will be able to circumvent these restrictions (using some clever scripts). So a *chroot* is probably preferable.

You could define a separate group for that user to refrain him from doing a lot more. See also the [nobody username](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobody_%28username%29), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SElinux), etc.