# Unix : Restricting a directory to an user

Tags: linux, security, shell, unix, ubuntu

I have a root user who has set of input files in a directory

`/home/root/inputs/input1.txt` .

I created another dummy user `/home/dummy` who cannot view the input files under /home/root/inputs . But this dummy user will be creating a c program and executing it. And this program should use the inputs under

```
 /home/root/inputs/input1.txt.
```

How can i achieve this ? 
I Do not want the dummy user to view the input file from his code (by using system(`ls`,`cat`)) but i want the dummy user to call the binary and use this input.

```
sudo -u dummy ./a.out < /home/root/inputs/input1.txt
```

is giving me permission denied.

Am creating this script for my class.

Comment: Nearly duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17943784/841108)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because `a.ou`t is not reading the file when you use `<`.  The shell is. You need to change a.out so it takes an argument, then you'll be able to run `sudo -u dummy ./a.out /home/root/inputs/input1.txt` and it will work.